# proof of a property of modular arithmetic

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I have been stuck in a problem related to modular arithmetic. I have tried it using the generalized Euler's formula for $\gcd(a,b)=as+bt$, but have not reached the proof so far.

The question is:

> Let $ a, b, n, n' $ all belong to integers($ \mathbb Z $) with $ n > 0
> > , n' > 0 $ and $ \gcd(n, n') = 1 $. Show that if $ a \equiv b \mod n $
>   and $ a \equiv b \mod {n'} $ then $ a \equiv b \mod {nn'} $.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $a \equiv b \mod n$ and $a \equiv b \mod n^\prime$, then there are integers $k$ and $k^\prime$ such that $kn = a - b = k^\prime n^\prime$. If $kn = k^\prime n^\prime$ and $(n,n^\prime) = 1$, then what is $(n,k^\prime)$?

Comment: i think if (n,n')=1 and kn=k'n' then should not k=n' and k'=n?

Comment: They aren't necessarily equal, but $n^\prime | k$ and $n | k^\prime$. So $a - b = mnn^\prime$, so what is $a - b \mod nn^\prime$?

Comment: okay, i got it. Thank you man.